# Возможна ли нотация аргументов и возвращаемых объектов функции в python в несколько типов?

Tags: python

в псевдокоде это бы выглядело как
функция бла_бла_функция(аргумент=значение по умолчанию -> int либо matrix либо vector) возвращает ->число, либо вектор, либо матрицу:
тело функции
(пример условный)

Comment: В питоне существуют аннотации типов, которые выглядят практически так, как вы сейчас показали, но эти аннотации на самом деле никак не ограничивают ввод и вывод функции, а служат лишь для их некоторого документирования

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from typing import Union


def foo(arg: Union[int, Matrix]) -> Union[int, Matrix]
    # some code
```

Answer (score 3):

В python нет подказок типов. Есть только так называемые «аннотации», которые могут быть любыми объектами и в программном смысле ни на что не влияют.
Это просто метаданные.

```
def abs(n: 'signed num') -> 'positive num':
    return -n if n < 0 else n
```

То, как могут использоваться эти аннотации, нужно смотреть в документации тех инструментов(линтеров), которые вы используете.

Библиотека [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) тем не менее, предлагает довольно обширный класс объектов для унификации аннотаций типов, чтобы их могли использовать и линтеры и IDE, и т.п.
Стоит изучить эту библиотеку, там есть несколько полезных для вас концептов([Union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union), например)

Comment: Первый абзац вашего ответа вообще лишний, автор про это и не спрашивал. Что касается сути - всё-таки есть стандартный модуль typing, у которого вполне конкретный инструментарий для данного случая.

Comment: Первый абзац не лишний. Почему вы считаете, что он лишний? Это важная информация в контексте этой темы.

Comment: 1. Автор не пишет ничего такого, из чего следовало бы, что он ожидает от аннотации типов каких-то проверок. 2. К чему вообще фраза про то, что в питоне нет "подсказок типов"? В вопросе вообще нет слова "подсказки". Не надо за автора вопроса додумывать что-то, а потом эти же собственные додумки опровергать.